# jquery-plugin-validation adding rules with loop

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

```
 rules: {
            cmp_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            cmp_surname: {
                 minlength: 2,
                 required: true
            }
}
```

For example I have form with 100 cmp_name input, how to add rules with loop?

I try this:

```
 rules: {
         for(var i=0; i<=100; i++ ){
          cmp_name+i{
            minlenght: 2;
            required: true         
          },
         }
}
```

But it's not working solution, maybe are some  like my method but working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [add rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)

```
$("form input").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Comment: But now I must add to inputs `id` ? or can use input name ?

Comment: the jquery selector will select all inputs in the forms found in the document, you could be more specific as to select the exact form using the form's id like `$("#myFormId input")` and even so selecting only the inputs you want like `$("#myFormId input[id^=cmp_]")`, take a look at the [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I think is not good solution because I use `.validate()` and I cant inside use something like this

Comment: call this after validate